# Bootstrap Image Responsive

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

In my css file I just added the class for responsive image (`img-responsive`) from Bootstrap documentation and it doesn't work.

```
 <div class="app">
     <div class="img-responsive">
          <img src="images/build-icon.png" alt="Icon of the App">
     </div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `.img-responsive` class needs to be on the image itself as per the [Bootstrap docs](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#images).

```
<img src="images/build-icon.png" class="img-responsive" alt="Icon of the App">
```

Although you would only need to add `max-width: 100%;` `height: auto;` and `display: block;` to the image to make it responsive.

Answer (score 0):

You add this class to `div` while it should be added to `img` ([doc](http://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_ref_css_images.asp)). Try to use this:

```
 <div class="app">
        <div><img src="images/build-icon.png" alt="Icon of the App" class="img-responsive"></div>
 </div>
```